# Seeking bash script for multi casting user input on keyboard and mouse to multiple browser tabs

Tags: bash, browser, tabs, automation, mouse

I got curious if it is possible to have multiple tabs open in a browser where all the tabs have identical content and be able to press a key or a mouseclick so that all tabs experience the same input. I believe my formulation of what I want to do may be confusing as searching this with my words has been fruitless. I will therefore illustrate with something specific:

In my case I want to have a few tabs on same window with the Google [search](https://www.google.ca/) present in all tabs. With one of the tabs selected as the current view in the browser.
I would then type in a query and click the first available link. My desired output would have all the tabs experience the query search and link click at the same time.

I would like to achieve this through bash scripting [not sure if this IS possible] and would be very grateful if I am provided with some examples and readings I can look at to get started on my example detailed above. If there are other approaches I would be happy to look at them as well. Preferably it would be something I could code and play around with.

I found a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/620282/clone-user-input-over-multiple-browser-tabs-for-testing-different-languages), but the question was not answered as it appears a little too general.

If it helps determine the answer: I am running Firefox 43 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Apologies in advance if the question appears a little vague. I will be more than happy to provide requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can send keyboard and mouse inputs to windows via the X server (which is the service which controls all graphical windows).

For example you can send an `F5` keypress to a Chrome window using the following

```
CHROME_WINDOW_ID="$(xdotool search --class Chrome | head -n 1)"
xdotool key --window "$CHROME_WINDOW_ID" F5
```

You can use `mouse_move` and `click` similarly; see [xdotool](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml) for more details.

I'm not sure you could do this to individual browser tabs (unless you get your script to click on the correct tab beforehand), but definitely for individual browser windows.

You might do something like this:

```
# Write all Chrome window IDs to array
xdotool search --class Chrome | tr '\n' ' ' | read -a WINDOW_IDS

for WINDOW in ${WINDOW_IDS[@]} ; do
    # Do actions on $WINDOW
done
```

*Edit:*
If your problem is specifically related to manipulating web pages, you might also want to check out browser automation tools such as [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), or [splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).